# Parameters inside other parameters - using bootstrap aggregation with random forests in ensemble learning

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, ensemble-learning

Let’s say I decide to use an ensemble method - if it makes a difference, we’ll use the iris dataset. Of the available ensemble techniques, we’ll focus on the parallel methods, and from those we’ll take bootstrap aggregation, using sklearn.

Sklearn implements bootstrap aggregation by using `BaggingClassifier`, which (the documentation tells us) is “an ensemble meta-estimator that fits base classifiers…” Of those base classifiers, let’s select `RandomForestClassifier`, which itself is “is a meta estimator that fits a number of decision tree classifiers”.

Bootstrap aggregation, we’re told, comes essentially in four flavors: bagging, pasting, random subspaces and random patches.  In `BaggingClassifier`, we activate each of these four flavors by manipulating 4 of the 11 parameters of `BaggingClassifier`, namely: `bootstrap_features` (True/False), `bootstrap` (True/False), `max_features` (=1/<1), and `max_samples` (=1/<1).

In sklearn, to use `BaggingClassifier` with `RandomForestClassifier` we need to:

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(parameters), parameters)
```

Turns out that among `RandomForestClassifier`’s 17 parameters, two are the same as those of `BaggingClassifier`’s: `bootstrap` and `max_features`. While `bootstrap` is the same for both `BaggingClassifier` and `RandomForestClassifier` (i.e., sampling with/without replacement), I’m not sure about `max_features`. In `BaggingClassifier`, `max_features` is “the number of features to draw from X to train”, in this case, `RandomForestClassifier`. While in `RandomForestClassifier`, it’s “the number of feature to consider when looking for the best split”.

And this, finally, brings me to the question: how do we coordinate these parameters in these two classifiers so we can get the four flavors of bootstrap aggregation in each of the trees in the random forest? I’m not just asking if something like this works as the pasting flavor:

```
clf=BaggingClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap = False, max_features = 1.0),
   bootstrap_features = False, bootstrap = False, max_features = 1.0, max_samples = 0.6 )
```

I’m really trying to actually understand what’s going on behind the scene when `BaggingClassifier` calls on `RandomForestClassifier` with all these parameters tuned to different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no conflict between the Random Forest parameters and the Ensemble Classifier parameters. The reason why Random Forest has similar parameters (btw, `max_features` is the same in the two, it is just phrased in a different way) is because Random Forest itself is an Ensemble algorithm.

Hence, what you are trying to achieve here is an Ensemble of Ensemble classifiers, where each has its own parameters. If I slightly change your example to make it easier to understand, we have:

```
BaggingClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, bootstrap = True, max_features = 0.5), n_estimators = 5,
   bootstrap_features = False, bootstrap = False, max_features = 1.0, max_samples = 0.6 )
```

This is how it would work:

- First the EnsembleClassifier would take all the features (which is given by `bootstrap_features = False, max_features = 1.0`) and draw 60% (`max_samples = 0.6`) of your sample without replacement (`bootstrap = False`)
- Then it feeds all the features and 60% of the sample to a RandomForest

  - The Random Forest selects 50% of the features without replacement (`max_features = 0.5`) passed by the Ensemble at the previous step (which, in our case, are all features) and does a bootstrap sampling (with replacement) of the 60% sample passed by the Ensemble Classifier. Based on this, it trains a Decision Tree and repeats this procedure `n_estimators = 100` times, with new features and new bootstraping

This is repeated `n_estimators = 5` times by the Ensemble Classifier.

Hope this helps!

TLDR: the parameters you pass to `RandomForestClassifier` and `EnsembleClassifier` might have the same name and actually do the same thing, they do it at different stages of the training process, and if you set `bootstrap = False` in one, it won't pass this parameter value to the other one.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for - now I'm enlighted :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)