# Grid search on parameters inside the parameters of a BaggingClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search, ensemble-learning

This is a follow up on [a question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487151/parameters-inside-other-parameters-using-bootstrap-aggregation-with-random-for), but I believe it deserves its own thread.

In the previous question, we were dealing with “an Ensemble of Ensemble classifiers, where each has its own parameters.”  Let's start with the example provided by [MaximeKan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10956606/maximekan) in his answer:

```
my_est = BaggingClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, bootstrap = True, 
      max_features = 0.5), n_estimators = 5, bootstrap_features = False, bootstrap = False, 
      max_features = 1.0, max_samples = 0.6 )
```

Now say I want to go one level above that: Considerations like efficiency, computational cost, etc., aside, and as a general concept: How would I ran grid search with this kind of setup?

I can set up two parameter grids along these lines:

One for the `BaggingClassifier`:

```
BC_param_grid = {
'bootstrap': [True, False],
'bootstrap_features': [True, False],    
'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15],
'max_samples' : [0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
}
```

And one for the `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
RFC_param_grid = {
'bootstrap': [True, False],    
'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
'max_features' : [0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
}
```

Now I can call grid search with my estimator:

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = my_est, param_grid = ???)
```

What do I do with the `param_grid` parameter in this case? Or more specifically, how do I use both of the parameter grids I set up?

I have to say, it feels like I’m playing with [matryoshka dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Comment: I recommend trying out the approach recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570307/tuning-parameters-of-the-classifier-used-by-baggingclassifier. Apparently, putting `base_estimator__<param name> = [...]`,  ie. `base_estimator__max_depth = [...]` in your `param_grid` is enough to tell GridSearchCV that that particular param list is for one of the hyperparameters of your base estimator (a RandomForestClassifier, in your case).

Comment: @James Dellinger - thanks, that worked! I followed your suggestion and expanded from there. I'll post the final version as an answer, for the benefit of our children and grandchildren...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @James Dellinger comment above, and expanding from there, I was able to get it done. Turns out the "secret sauce" is indeed a mostly-undocumented feature - the  `__`  (double underline) separator (there's some passing reference to it in the [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) documentation): it seems that adding the inside/base estimator name, followed by this `__` to the name of an inside/base estimator parameter, allows you to create a `param_grid` which covers parameters for both the outside and inside estimators.

So for the example in the question, the outside estimator is `BaggingClassifier` and the inside/base estimator is `RandomForestClassifier`. So what you need to do is, first, to import what needs to be imported:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

followed by the `param_grid` assignments (in this case, those in example in the question):

```
param_grid = {
 'bootstrap': [True, False],
 'bootstrap_features': [True, False],    
 'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15],
 'max_samples' : [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
 'base_estimator__bootstrap': [True, False],    
 'base_estimator__n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
 'base_estimator__max_features' : [0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
}
```

And, finally, your grid search:

```
grid_search=GridSearchCV(BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=RandomForestClassifier()), param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)
```

And you're off to the races.